# How do I create an editable PHP/HTML template without security risk?

Tags: php, html, kohana

Using a Kohana View class, I want admin users to be able to edit HTML templates and the easiest way to do this is to let them edit the template file directly i.e. load it in a textarea and save file on submit.

But a malicious user could potentially write php code inside this textarea and call static functions that may cause malicious behaviour. How can I restrict PHP to only evaluate simple variables in this editable template and disallow function calls and other types of logic?

Example:
view/template.php

```
Hey $firstname,

Best regards,
$admin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't parse the php. Read it into a string using `file_get_contents` and do a `str_replace` with a list of known variables.

e.g.

```
$replace = array(
    '$firstname' => $firstname,
    '$admin' => $admin
);
$template = file_get_contents('view/template.php');
$template = str_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $template);
```

This obviously gets more complicated if you want to let them do anything more advanced than your example, but that's what things like [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) are for.

Comment: I like your answer but it means I cannot make use of my backend framework: http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/mvc/views#views for this particular functionality

Comment: That's not entirely true. You can still use views, this would simply end up as a variable that you pass to a parent template. You're going to have all the variables right next to this in the controller anyway. Another option might be to parse (rather than include) Kohana::find_file from within a parent template but I don't think that's the right place

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use some templateing engine like [mustache](https://github.com/zombor/KOstache).